# Making anti-clock to the progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a progress bar using div, I got some code to create but that's clock-wise, instead, I need it in anti-clockwise

There are some HTML and CSS code, with which simple progress bar is created, my problem is that I can't use other technologies for it, so using only HTML,CSS I have to create it. Please help out to me in it.

```css
    .progress-circle {
       font-size: 20px;
       margin: 20px;
       position: relative; /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
       padding: 0;
       width: 5em;
       height: 5em;
       background-color: #F2E9E1; 
       border-radius: 50%;
       line-height: 5em;
    }
    
    .progress-circle:after{
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.35em;
        left: 0.35em;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 4.3em;
        height: 4.3em;
        background-color: white;
        content: " ";
    }
    /* Text inside the control */
    .progress-circle span {
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 5em;
        width: 5em;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        color: #53777A;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .left-half-clipper { 
       /* a round circle */
       border-radius: 50%;
       width: 5em;
       height: 5em;
       position: absolute; /* needed for clipping */
       clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em); /* clips the whole left half*/ 
    }
    /* when p>50, don't clip left half*/
    .progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
       clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
    }
    .value-bar {
       /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
       then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
       to escape the outer clipping path.*/ 
       position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
       clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
       width: 5em;
       height: 5em;
       border-radius: 50%;
       border: 0.45em solid #53777A; /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
       /*background-color: #4D642D;*/ /* for debug */
       box-sizing: border-box;
      
    }
    /* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */
    .progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
       /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
       position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
       clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
       background-color: #53777A;
       border-radius: 50%;
       width: 5em;
       height: 5em;
    }
    .progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar{ display: none; }
    
    
    /* Progress bar rotation position */
    .progress-circle.p0 .value-bar { display: none; }
    .progress-circle.p1 .value-bar { transform: rotate(4deg); }
    .progress-circle.p2 .value-bar { transform: rotate(7deg); }
    .progress-circle.p3 .value-bar { transform: rotate(11deg); }
    .progress-circle.p4 .value-bar { transform: rotate(14deg); }
    .progress-circle.p5 .value-bar { transform: rotate(18deg); }
    .progress-circle.p6 .value-bar { transform: rotate(22deg); }
    .progress-circle.p7 .value-bar { transform: rotate(25deg); }
    .progress-circle.p8 .value-bar { transform: rotate(29deg); }
    .progress-circle.p9 .value-bar { transform: rotate(32deg); }
    .progress-circle.p10 .value-bar { transform: rotate(36deg); }
```

```html
  <div class="progress-circle p10">
       <span>10%</span>
       <div class="left-half-clipper">
          <div class="first50-bar"></div>
          <div class="value-bar"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want the progress bar should be anti-clockwise instead of clockwise

Comment: a trivial solution would be to add `scalex(-1)` to the whole element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **scale()** CSS function defines a transformation that resizes an element on the 2D plane. Using this transform function we can do this:

1. Add `transform: scale(-1, 1);` to  .progress-circle.
2. Add `transform: scale(-1, 1);` to  .progress-circle span.

[Here's demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/6fagecyx/2/)